# Disable a key press event through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-events

I need to disable <kbd>shift</kbd> keypress event in my site by using JavaScript or any other method.
Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
document.onkeydown = checkKeycode
function checkKeycode(e) {
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) {
        keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    }
    else if (e) {
        keycode = e.which;
    }
    //alert(keycode);
    if (keycode == 16) {
        alert(keycode);
        return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is not a code request forum. Explain what you tried...add some code, show examples and explain the problem.

Comment: @Neon i need to be briefed....

Answer (score 8):

```
// bind an event listener to the keydown event on the window
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {

    // if the keyCode is 16 ( shift key was pressed )
    if (event.keyCode === 16) {

        // prevent default behaviour
        event.preventDefault();

        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: @Macraze it really depends on a lot of things, is the event delegated correctly ? does any other piece of code over rights the event ? how are you debugging ? what is the exact expected behavior ? etc.

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

> In addition, modifier keys (**such as Shift**) trigger keydown events but not keypress events.

Try this

```
$('#target').keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.shiftKey) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
     var e = e || event;

     if (e.shiftKey === true) {
          return false;
     }
};
```

Comment: Works well for me in Firefox 8.0.1 http://jsfiddle.net/1stein/hvcQ7/ Do you really want to disable **Shift** key?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 16) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
    console.log(e.which);
});
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjAxB/).

Use Firebug and check console output.