# JQuery on click or on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have buttons that have accesskey='whateverKey' I have a jQuery that is ran when the document is ready. I want to be able to disable the alt key and only have it highlight the button instead of submit it. Which can be done if you put in a onClick='if(checkIfAlt())gotoPage' on every single button. is it possible to do that in a .ready? without having every button use the onClick?

I need it ran in this....

```
jQuery( document ).ready({

}
```

I have tried all of these

```
jQuery(document).on('button', 'form', function(event) {
    alert('clicked');
    event.preventDefault();
});

jQuery(document).bind("keydown", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});

$("button").click(function(evt) {
    if (evt.ctrlKey)
        alert('Ctrl down');
    if (evt.altKey)
        alert('Alt down');
});
```

Some of these are out there but I was just trying a bunch of stuff trying to figure out how to get this to work. Is this possible?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

To disable the alt and/or the control keys you can do this - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/uwPrV/

```
$('body').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 17 || e.keyCode == 18) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        console.log(e.keyCode);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this too, even replaced 'body' with document and it doesnt prevent it. I did an alert() and it does alert me but doesnt prevent the (altKey + accessKey) submitting the button.

Comment: I tested this in a couple of browsers and both the alt and control keys were disabled, they did not provided anything on keydown. Can you provide a fiddle showing that these keys are not disabled when using this code?

Comment: Actually it prevents the CTRL key, but shows the keydown of the 'h' key. If you are using key combo's you'll always get 2 keycodes (or more if there is a complex sequence, like CTRL + ALT + DEL). So the CTRL key is properly disabled while the 'h' key is still enabled - as it should be. Did you expect to get a different keycode back when pressing two keys? Watch the console as you press.

Comment: You may to use keypress() depending on the browser. Here is more info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269274/disable-a-key-press-event-through-java-script