# How to have keypresses not work on input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I just want to add a simple feature to my Reddit userscript that enables me to press E on a post and it clicks the upvote button, I managed to do it with this code in jQuery but it also works when I'm typing in any input field, I don't know how to make it stop.

**CODE:**

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $(document).keypress((e)=>{
      if(e.key === 'e'){
          //$('.voteButton[data-click-id="upvote"]')[0].click();
          console.log('clicked!');
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

**NOTE:** The question which this is supposed to be a duplicate of does help me but does not fix my problem directly, adding `if($(e.target).is('input,select,button,textarea,div[role="textbox"]')) return;` is what fixed it, apparently Reddit uses wrappers for text fields so I had to add `div[role="textbox"]` which is the "textbox" used, the thing is I will have to manually add custom selection for all of these wrapped elements.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269274/disable-a-key-press-event-through-java-script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try if the event element is a input then leave from function:

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $(document).keypress((e)=>{
      if($(e.target).is('input')) return
      if(e.key === 'e'){
          //$('.voteButton[data-click-id="upvote"]')[0].click();
          console.log('clicked!');
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited the answer i was thinking that you want the event just on the input

you could just select the input using id like this

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("document").keypress(e => { 
    if (e.key === "e") {
      if($("#input").is(":focus")) return null // here is change 
      //$('.voteButton[data-click-id="upvote"]')[0].click();
      console.log("clicked!");
    }
  });
});
```

```
    <input id="input" type="text" />  // here a change to your code
```